# Get day of week in PHP

Tags: php

If I have a date, month and a year values, is there a way in PHP to calculate the day of the week?
I don't mean today's day of the week, but any date in the future of in the past.

Comment: you want to get the day of a date?

Comment: Read the PHP date function documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: 2,000 rep and you don't know how to Google?

Answer (score 1):

```
$day_of_week = date ('l', strtotime ('2012-06-11 13:43:23'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo date('l',strtotime('3 March 2013'));`

returns Sunday.

`echo date('l',mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year));`

returns appropriately for integer values of month, day and year.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
echo date('l j \of F Y', strtotime('2013-03-02'));
```

If you only want the day of the week change the first argument to just l.

[PHP Date documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) has a very good list of what information you can "extract" from the date.